# CMD/BAT - построчное чтение > запись

Tags: cmd, bat

Здравствуйте. Имеется файл с примерным содержанием:

```
#text
text2
text3
#text4
text5
```

Мне нужно построчно прочесть файл и если первый символ строки не # записать в другой файл в виде "какой-то_текст строка_из_первого_файла". Тоесть отработав на файле из примера скрипт должен выдать мне:

```
какой-то_текст text2 
какой-то_текст text3 
какой-то_текст text5
```

Я пробовал так:

```
set file=file.txt
for %%i in (%file%) do (
    set test=%%i
    set var=%package:~0,1%
    if not "%var%" == "#" echo "какой-то_текст %test%" >> new_file.txt )
```

Но ничего не получается.
Посоветовали:

```
for /f %%i in ('findstr /v ^# file.txt') do echo какой-то_текст %%i >> new_file.txt
```

Но тоже не работает.
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@FOR /F %x IN ('findstr /B /V /C:# file.txt') DO @ECHO какой-то_текст %x >> file2.txt
```

Если код в батнике удвой знак процента. Ну и с кодировкой не напаши...

Comment: Все работает, спасибо.